# php fatal error- Catchable fatal error: Object of class

Tags: php, oop

I am getting fatal error-

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class TV could not be converted to
>   string in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/oop/index.php on line 31.

What is is wrong here?

```
<?php

/**
* 
*/
class TV {

    public $model= 'xyz';
    public $volume= 1;

    function volumeUp()
    {
        $this->volume++;
    }

    function volumeDown() 
    {
        $this->volume--;
    }
}
//here we create new objects
$tv_one = new TV;
$tv_two = new TV;
//
$tv_one->volumeUp();

echo $tv_one->volume;

$tv_one->model;
//error on the following line
echo $tv_one;
```

Comment: echo $tv_one; this is line 31th

Comment: `$tv_one` is an object. You can't just echo it. If you want to get the volume, use `$tv_one->volume`

Comment: Fetal error! Someone call a prenatal physician STAT!

Comment: `echo $tv_one` is bombing. In order to be able to `echo`, your class (TV) must provide a __toString() method e.g. convert to string.

Comment: You might be trying to `var_dump($tv_one);`

Comment: And of course you can echo an object, implement the magical method [__toString](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) and you're good to go ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid statement to print a value to the page:

```
echo $tv_one->volume;
```

This isn't doing anything:

```
$tv_one->model;
```

It resolves to a value, but you don't *do anything* with that value.  So that line of code is entirely useless and can just be removed.

This doesn't make sense:

```
echo $tv_one;
```

What do you expect the *object* to look like on the page?  You `echo` values, not entire structures.  So, *exactly* as you *already do* above, echo the value you want:

```
echo $tv_one->model;
```

Comment: echo $tv_one->volume; should say 1

Comment: @lolka_bolka: I'm not sure what you mean, can you clarify?